# form_for not submit all fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, save

**Use a hidden field will fix my issue... i got it..**

Hi All,

I am new to rails, trying to do some practice.
The app i am writing is trying to create a new "Post" See the view and controller below.

But it doesn`t work as what i expected... 
the parameters pass to function "save", there is no "post_at" field...

How can i fix it???
Thanks

```
INFO:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Xc9VuvRL6GsUTaKyyNQxp8ovylEYwOMC+7hMcqdKizg=", "post"=>{"title"=>"First post", "content"=>"Write something"}, "commit"=>"save"}
```

View new_post.erb

```
<div class="post">
  <% form_for @new_post, :url => { :action => "save" } do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.error_messages %></p>
    <br/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :title %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Post at</td>
        <td><%= @new_post.post_at %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Message</td>
        <td><%= f.text_area :content, :cols => 100, :rows => 10 %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <%= f.submit 'save'%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Post Controler

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @all_posts = Post.find(:all)

    render :action => "post"
  end

  def new
    @new_post = Post.new
    @new_post.post_at = Time.now

    render :action => "new_post"
  end

  def save
    @new_post = params[:post]
    Post.create(@new_post)

    redirect_to "/post"
  end
end
```

Data Model:

```
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource
  storage_names[:default] = "Post"

  property :id,      Serial
  timestamps :at

  property :title,        String,        :required => true, :length => 500
  property :content,      Text,          :required => true, :lazy => false
  property :post_at,      DateTime
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your development will be a lot easier if you follow the [REST principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer).

Your controller should instead of `save` implement the `create` and `update` methods.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.create(params[:post])
  redirect_to @post
end

def show
  @post = Post.get(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @post = Post.get(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = Post.get(params[:id])
  @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
  redirect_to @post
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.get(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

This is a complete REST controller which has the views `index.html.erb, new.html.erb, edit.html.erb, show.html.erb` all in `app/views/posts`.

Sidenote: If you're new to Rails, it might be a good idea to learn how to use it with ActiveRecord before trying on DataMapper. That way you can use `rails generate scaffold` to get a full example of a way to do all this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `post_at` value isn't a field, it's just displayed in the table. You want to do this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Post at</td>
  <td><%= f.datetime_select :post_at %></td>
</tr>
```

But in fact, there's more wrong with this code than that. For starters, Rails already has a field for this which will be set automatically called `created_at`. Next, your `save` action in your controller should be a `create` action to follow the Rails conventions.

I really think you should read the [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) guide which covers these basic fundamentals and then [a book](http://manning.com/katz) [or two](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails) about Rails in more depth. These really teach you a lot.

Comment: but i don`t want to edit the time, just want to show it there

Comment: and about the "create_at", coz i am using appengine-jruby, they do not have that field...

Answer (score 0):

Ryan is right about the cause of the problem.

If you need a readonly field then you could add a hidden field to make sure that the value is posted back:

```
    <td><%= @new_post.post_at %><%= f.hidden_field :post_at %></td>
```

or you could replace it altogether with a readonly text_field:

```
    <td><%= f.text_field :post_at, :readonly => true %></td>
```